# How many votes are needed to be a standby block producer as of today (2018 Oct 23) and how much does one earn while as a stand by?

Tags: voting

From my understanding you get 30 votes per EOS?

And how many votes or EOS does one need to have in order to be a stand by block producer? And how much does one make in a day as a stand by block producer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://eosauthority.com/producers_rank

According to the stats above the last stand-by bp has 21.5 million votes. And earns 108 eos/day.

Comment: How does one get that many votes? that's about 7 million eos one would need. or 35 million dollars worth of EOS to make $500 a day.

Comment: Hopefully from the community. It's not supposed to be buy EOS to vote yourself.